# Does weak convergence to a continuous distribution imply strong convergence of measures?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of real-valued random variables with cumulative distribution function $F_n$. Let $X$ be another real-valued random variable with CDF $F$.

[Here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Essentials_of_Probability_Theory_for_Sta/0DH3DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=joint%20distribution%20weak%20convergence&pg=PA236&printsec=frontcover) it is stated that $F_n$ converges strongly to $F$ if $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The book cites [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25049174) as a reference. However, the paper defines strong convergence of measures (say $\mu_n$ converges strongly to $\mu$) if $\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A)$ for every set $A$ in the sigma field on which measures are defined.

Are these two equivalent i.e. strong convergence of cdfs implies strong convergence of measures defined by the cdfs ?

Comment: I made a mistake in my original post in considering $A\setminus A_{m}$ to lie in $\mathcal{G}$. Anyways, ignore that if you have forgotten about it. There are "uncountably" many counterexamples. As I said, you can show that if a sequence of cdf's converge to a continuous cdf then the convergence is uniform. So in particular, if you take a sequence of any discrete distributions $\mu_{n}\sim X_{n}$. Then by CLT, $Y_{n}=\frac{S_{n}-E(S_{n})}{\sqrt{n}}\to N(0,1)$. If $D_{n}$ are supports of $Y_{n}$ , then $\bigcup D_{n}$ is a set for which you don't have convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please notice following example. Let
\begin{equation*}
 F_n(x)=\frac{[n(x^+\wedge 1)]}{n}, \quad n\ge 1,\qquad F(x)=x^+\wedge 1,\quad x\in\mathbb{R},  \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
$\mu_n,\mu$ be the measures generated by $F_n,F$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ respectively. Then, as $n\to\infty$,
\begin{equation*}
  \mu_n\overset{w}{\to} \mu,\qquad F_n(x)\to F(x), \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
Also,  let
\begin{equation*}
 A_n=\Big\{\frac{k}{n}, k=0,1,\cdots,n\Big\},\quad n\ge1,\qquad A=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n, 
\end{equation*}
then $A_n,A$ are countable and
\begin{gather*}
 \mu_n(A_n)=\mu_n(A)=1,\qquad n\ge 1,  \tag{3}\\
 \mu(A_n)=\mu(A)=0, \qquad n\ge 1.  \tag{4}
\end{gather*}
(2)--(4) means that weak convergence (to a continuous distribution) does not
imply "strong convergence" of measures.

Comment: I made a mistake in my original post in considering $A\setminus A_{m}$ to lie in $\mathcal{G}$. Anyways, ignore that if you have forgotten about it. There are "uncountably" many counterexamples. As I said, you can show that if a sequence of cdf's converge to a continuous cdf then the convergence is uniform. So in particular, if you take a sequence of any discrete distributions $\mu_{n}\sim X_{n}$. Then by CLT, $Y_{n}=\frac{S_{n}-E(S_{n})}{\sqrt{n}}\to N(0,1)$. If $D_{n}$ are supports of $Y_{n}$ , then $\bigcup D_{n}$ is a set for which you don't have convergence.

Comment: This one in particualr is for $\mu_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\delta_{\frac{k}{n}}$ which converges to uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ which is easy to show by use of Portmanteau theorem. i.e. for any continuous and bounded $f$, we have $\int f\,d\mu_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(\frac{k}{n})=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ by usual Riemann sums and the right hand side is just $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f\,d\mu$ where $\mu$ is the uniform measure on $[0,1]$. So, in particular if you take any sequence of discrete distributions converging to a continuous one, then you'll get a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

I made a mistake in my original post in considering $A\setminus A_{m}$ to lie in $\mathcal{G}$. Anyways, ignore that if you have forgotten about it. There are "uncountably" many counterexamples. As I said, you can show that if a sequence of cdf's converge to a continuous cdf then the convergence is uniform. So in particular, if you take a sequence of any discrete iid random variables $X_{n}$. Then by CLT, $\mu_{n}\sim Y_{n}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}-E(\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k})}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\to N(0,1)=\mu$ (say). If $D_{n}$ (discrete) are supports of $Y_{n}$ , then $\bigcup D_{n}$ is a set for which you don't have convergence as $\mu_{n}(\bigcup D_{n})=1$ but $\mu(\bigcup D_{n})=0$

The above example by JGWang in particualr is for $\mu_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\delta_{\frac{k}{n}}$ which converges to uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ which is easy to show by use of Portmanteau theorem. i.e. for any continuous and bounded $f$, we have $\int f\,d\mu_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(\frac{k}{n})=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ by usual Riemann sums and the right hand side is just $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f\,d\mu$ where $\mu$ is the uniform measure on $[0,1]$.

So, in particular if you take any sequence of discrete distributions converging to a continuous one, then you'll get a counterexample.